# How to integrate worldpay payment gateway with django app?

Tags: python, django, payment-gateway, worldpay

I am trying to integrate worldpay payment gateway into my django app. In their documentation there is only cURL provided for reference. Can anyone help me how to get started with it using python requests or urllib module?

You can test this project out with this repo: https://github.com/Hinal1012/payment-demo.git

Comment: Maybe try linking the snippet you were talking about, or at least show what you've already tried?

Comment: Hi @Xiddoc, You can test this demo project with my github repo https://github.com/Hinal1012/payment-demo.git

Comment: What is going wrong when you try to integrate it?

Comment: It shows "Unsupported payment method as HCG is no longer supported" error while testing online card payment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved... I think this issue was a bug in their system. Because the team was migratng existing community to new platform. Now it's working. Thanks.

Comment: hi sir, could you help me to integrate the worldpay in to my django.